# How to Integrate web-cam with a web page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, webcam

I am developing a web application using Java (Servlet, JSP). In a JSP page, I want to show the web camera window to the user. When client clicks a button "Capture", then I should be able to capture the image and store it in some place.

I have done a lot of research, but could not find a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's where the beauty of Applet comes in. Facebook has an Applet that connects to the PC camera and does capturing.

Comment: can you please help me how to do that? Or atleast please send a link describing this.

Comment: I guess you have to learn [Applet](http://java.sun.com/applets/) and figure out how to connect to the PC camera.

Answer (score 0):

This site provides a good example in JSP:

http://thenerdinme.com/do-it-yourself/how-to-take-screenshots-with-java/

Comment: What is the class Robot there in the snippet provided by the given link.

Comment: Robot is part of Java AWT (see [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class) which is standard in Java JDK/JRE.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about Robot class.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use something like flex which provides better support for this?

Comment: I don't know anything about flex. So I can't go for that.

Comment: http://tinkerlog.com/2007/11/03/webcam-snapshots-with-flex3/Flex is much much easier if youve managed to learn java. Here is an sample app. Some times Google helps..;)...